# Why is the non-const pointer being treated as a const when using typedef?

Tags: c, pointers, constants

```
typedef char* c;
const c ptr1 = "pointer";
++ptr1; /// error
const char* ptr2 = "pointer";
++ptr2; /// runs fine
```

Now `ptr1` should be of type `const char*` and thus a non-const pointer, then why is it being treated as a constant pointer ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are not the same.

The first designates a const-pointer-to-char, the second is a pointer-to-const-char.

Try reading right to left:

```
const char *p;  // p is a pointer to char which is const
char const *p;  // p is a pointer to const char (same as previous)
char * const p; // p is a const pointer to char
char const * const p; // p is a const pointer to const char
```

By using the typedef `typedef char* c` you pack the meaning "pointer to char" into a single alias `c`:

```
const c p; // p is a const [c] --> p is a const [pointer to char]
```

---

**Additional explanations:**

Typedefs are not in-place-expanded like macros are, i.e.

```
const c p;
```

really becomes

```
const [char*] p;
```

it does *not* become

```
const char* p; // Nope.
```

Don't expand it like macros in your mind, with the typedefs, you've bound `char` and `*` together and formed an atom.

Comment: This is interesting. I'm really surprised. +1

Comment: I know that, but when shouldn't it be treated as *const char* * by the compiler, because *c* being expanded to *char* *, that's what I'm asking.

Comment: @cirronimbo: See the section "by using the typedef" in my answer.

Comment: I got into the habit of writing *type* const for this reason, but it seems to drive other programmers (who don't have a good grasp of the language) crazy. I actually think that the standard should rule putting const in front to be obsolescent and eventually outlaw it.

Comment: @cirronimbo `c` is not expanded; `typedef` isn't a textual macro facility. Or, to look at it another way, it implicitly puts parens around the type, so `const c` is `const (char*)` rather than `(const char)*`.

Comment: @JimBalter: I personally use both forms. I usually choose what is better readable depending on context. Probably this drives even more programmers crazy :)

Comment: @JimBalter_Yeah I know, it was just that I could not find a better word to explain the thing :)

Comment: @cirronimbo See my edited comment. The point is that the expansion is structural, not textual, and so the grouping is different.

Answer (score 3):

`ptr1` is a `const (char *)`, meaning the pointer itself is a const, whereas `ptr2` is a `(const char) *`, meaning the target of the pointer is const.

Answer (score 0):

it has to do with the way that c groups things internally. A typedef isn't like a macro, it doesn't just substitute things in. If you were to pus parenthesis in it would look like this.

```
const (char*) ptr1 = "pointer";
(const char)* ptr2 = "pointer";
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing it like:

```
typedef char* c;
c const ptr1 = "pointer";
++ptr1; /// error
char const* ptr2 = "pointer";
++ptr2; /// runs fine
```

makes the difference more visible, and this should be the same as your example