# using type alias doesn't work with "const" pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, constants, using

Here, `const` pointer hold the address of `const` variable. like :

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{    
    const int i = 5;
    const int* ptr = &i;
}
```

It's working fine.

But, If I use [using (Type alias)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) like:

```
#include <iostream>

using intptr = int*;

int main() {    
    const int i = 5;
    const intptr ptr = &i;
}
```

GCC compiler gives an error. [[Live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mdrAkLXkTcD0CpZa)

Why pointer does not work with `using` Type alias?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864964/why-is-the-non-const-pointer-being-treated-as-a-const-when-using-typedef

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224827/typedef-with-const-and-without-const-qualifier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const intptr ptr` is an equivalent of `int * const ptr` - const pointer to non-const int, not `const int * ptr` - non-const pointer to const int.

If you find such right-to-left reading order for pointer declarations confusing you can utilize [Straight declarations](https://github.com/guaranteed-to-be-unique/Straight-Declarations) library which supplies alias templates to declare pointer types with left-to-right reading order:

```
const ptr<int> p; // const pointer to non-const int
ptr<const int> p; // non-const pointer to const int
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that for `const intptr`, `const` is a top-level qualifier on `intptr`. So `const` is qualified on the pointer itself, then `const intptr` means `int* const` (i.e. `const` pointer to non-`const` `int`), not `const int*` (i.e. non-`const` pointer to `const` `int`).

Answer (score 0):

The `const` keyword is actually binding to the word to the left of it. The notable exception is when the only word it can bind to is on the right hand side.

This means `const int* ptr` can be rewritten as `int const* ptr` while
`const intptr ptr` is equivalent to `intptr const ptr` which is `int *const ptr`.